# IntelliJ in "blocked" mode when window comes into focus

Tags: intellij-idea

I use i3 as a window manager. When I switch focus to Intellij (actually WebStorm but it's the same engine underneath), the cursor doesn't appear. I have found that hitting `ctrl+f->esc` is a workaround to get the cursor back (going into the IDE search and exiting again). Alternatively, I can *click* on the editor field of the IDE to make the cursor appear. However, it's not possible for me to just switch focus to the IDE and start using my vim bindings (or type text for that matter.

So:

1. focus on IDE
2. move focus away (left, right, whatever) and back again
3. no cursor -> ctrl+f--esc -> cursor back in previous mode

Oddly enough this doesn't occur in PyCharm. I imported all settings from pycharm into webstorm but the error persists. Disabling IdeaVIM doesn't help either.

Is there a setting, or a configuration that allows the definition of a "focus point" whenever the IDE window gets into the window managers focus? Or is there a known bug that relates to this?

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194124) that is expected to be fixed in 2018.3 EAP.

Citing two answers:

> A workaround that has been working for me for a few months now (and across multiple 2018.2, 2018.3 versions) is restarting i3 inplace when the IDE is focused. (The default command to restart i3 inplace is $mod+Shift+r). After doing this once, this problem goes away for me.

and

> UPD: it seems that setting suppress.focus.stealing=false in custom properties fixes the issue for me.

which can be set [like so](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html):

- Click Help > Edit Custom VM Options...
- Add this line:

  ```
  -Dsuppress.focus.stealing=false
  ```
- Restart the IDE.